# Correct data structure for fast insert and fast search?

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures, collections

I have an array and I need to insert items there as fast as possible. Before adding an item I need to see if it exists, so I do a full array scan. I can't use binary search since I can't sort the array after every insert.

Is there a more efficient data structure for this job?

**Edit**: On that array I store strings. Next to each string I store a 4 byte hash. I first compare the hashes and if they are the same then the string.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red%E2%80%93black_tree

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`std::unordered_map` usually implemented as ([hashtable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table)) will give you best insert/search time (O(1)) but does not preserve nor provide any order.

[`std::map`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/) gives you O(log(n)) for search and insert as it requires particular ordering (not the one you got to insert items so) and usually implemented with balanced tree.

Custom [balanced search trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-balancing_binary_search_tree) are another option if you need sorted order and fast (O(log n)) insert/search.

Sorted [`std::vector`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/) (to support ability to add items) is another option if O(n) is acceptable insert time but you need smallest memory footprint and O(log n) search time. You'd need to insert items in sorted order which is O(n) due to need to copy the rest of the array.

If you need to preserve original order you stuck with O(n) for both insert/search if you are using just an array ('std::vector').

You can use separate `std::unordered_map`/`std::unordered_set` in addition to 'std::vector' to add "is already present" check to gain speed at price of essentially 2-3x memory space and need to update 2 structures when adding items. This array+hashtable combination will give you O(n) insert and O(1) search.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Since performance and memory usage are a concern, can you please provide more information on how I can implement that myself?

Comment: @SilverWarrior Search for "read black tree" or "balance search tree" to find samples of trees.

Comment: I think you meant `std::unordered_map`.

Comment: `std::map` is not a hash table, it is usually implemented as a red black tree. `std::unordered_map` is a hash table.

Comment: Thanks @mattnewport, and chris  for useful feedback. Unfortunately answer was accepted so I had to edit it instead of  simply deleting.